# bcrypt-ruby failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I'm new to RoR and hit a snag with installing the bcrypt-ruby (v 3.0.1) gem (from gemfile) when following RailsTutorial.org. In looking through other responses on the site, what's not clear to me is if this a is version incompatibility issue, a missing ruby-dev environment, something to do with Xcode, an extra space in the "ruby extconf.rb" or something else. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

My environment = OS X v 10.8, Ruby 1.9.3p194 and Rails 3.2.6.

```
tj$ bundle install  
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........  
Using rake (0.9.2.2)   
Using i18n (0.6.0)  
Using multi_json (1.3.6)  
Using activesupport (3.2.6)  
Using builder (3.0.0)   
Using activemodel (3.2.6)   
Using erubis (2.7.0)  
Using journey (1.0.4)   
Using rack (1.4.1)   
Using rack-cache (1.2)   
Using rack-test (0.6.1)   
Using hike (1.2.1)   
Using tilt (1.3.3)   
Using sprockets (2.1.3)   
Using actionpack (3.2.6)   
Using mime-types (1.19)   
Using polyglot (0.3.3)   
Using treetop (1.4.10)   
Using mail (2.4.4)  
Using actionmailer (3.2.6)   
Using arel (3.0.2)   
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)   
Using activerecord (3.2.6)   
Using activeresource (3.2.6)   
Using addressable (2.3.1)  
Using annotate (2.5.0) 

Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/tj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-    p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.  
Results logged to /Users/tj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/bcrypt-    ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out  
An error occured while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you don't have `make` on your system. If you're using a Mac, you need to install the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Thanks, Veraticus. That did the trick. I appreciate the help!

Comment: btw: you can find the command line tools here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-# (login required)